# is there any way to create query including function in projection and outer apply in sqlkata?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlkata

I need some advance feature of SQL inside sqlkata such as outer apply of IIF expression inside the projection.
is there any way to create such query inside sqlkata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is by using the `SelectRaw` method.

```
query.SelectRaw("IIF(a > b, 'larger', 'smaller') as col").Select("Id");
```

Comment: this is for IIF  function but what about outer apply?