# Is it possible to query a parametrized table-valued function in sqlkata?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, sqlkata

I have a SQL table-valued function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Foo] (@bar VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS @result TABLE 
(
    [Column1] INT,
    [Column2] INT,
    [Column3] INT,
    [Column4] INT
)
..
```

I'd like to be able to perform queries against it in SqlKata, by calling the function with a proper parameter.

Is it possible? If so how?

Note: This question is somehow related to [is there any way to create query including function in projection and outer apply in sqlkata?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50664491/1288109) , but I need to pass a parameter too.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use [`FromRaw`](https://sqlkata.com/docs/from#from-a-raw-expression)

```
new Query().FromRaw("[Foo](?)", bar).Select("Column")
```

Side note: using the `QueryFactory` is way easier than executing the query by yourself.

```
var result = db.Query().FromRaw("[Foo](?)", bar).Select("Column").Get();
```

Comment: Can I change the parameter name in the query condition?

  query.WhereIn(Product, Value)    

this will become,

    WHERE ([Product].[Name] = @p0)    

but I need proper parameter name like,

    WHERE ([Product].[Name] = @productName)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the result accessing the my function like a CTE, i.e.: using WithRaw and an alias:

```
            var query = new Query("MyAlias")
                .WithRaw("MyAlias", "Select Column1 from [Foo](@bar)" )
                .Select("Column1");
            var compiled = _compiler.Compile(query);
            var result1 = connection.Query(compiled.Sql, new {bar = bar})
                .ToList();
```